# Iterating over a Backbone model's attributes and passing them to a function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to validate my model attributes by explicitly calling a validate function.
I'm not sure how to do that exactly,

```
collection.forEach(function (model) {
                model.forEach(function(attribute) {
                    someFunction(attribute);
                })
            });
```

this is the behavior I'd like to achieve somehow

Answer (score 3):

You can use `collection.each` to iterate over the models and [`_.each`](http://underscorejs.org/#each) on the keys of the model to apply your function:

```
collection.each(function(model) {
    _.each(model.keys(), function(attribute) {
        console.log(attribute, model.get(attribute));
    });
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/6YP9W/

Or work directly with the [attributes hash](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-attributes) if you prefer

```
collection.each(function(model) {
    _.each(model.attributes, function(val, attribute) {
        console.log(attribute, val);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6YP9W/1/

Answer (score 0):

You better use the backbone manner described in this [post](http://beletsky.net/2012/11/baby-steps-to-backbonejs-model.html)... Excellent guide :)

Comment: Dag Geert. Thanks for the article, I'll definitely read it. My main question, however, was how to iterate through model's attributes. Models have attributes property which gets model's attributes, but i think as JSON objects